# Java String Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class pro19 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word;
        System.out.print("Enter word: ");
        word = in.nextLine();
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(word);
        int l = word.length();
        for(int i = 1; i<=l; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j<=l; j++)
            {
                if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j))
                {
                    s = s.deleteCharAt(j);

                l--;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Word after deletion of duplicate letters: "+s);
}
```

}

I wrote this program to delete duplicate characters as school homework.
But whenever I run it I get the following output(exercise being the input):

Enter word: exercise

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at pro19.main(pro19.java:19)
```

Please help and tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Java is zero based, `for(int i = 1; i<=l; i++)`, should be `for(int i = 0; i<l; i++)`. Minor detail, but you should use `StringBuilder` over `StringBuffer`, since you don't need threaded access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Write

```
for(int i = 1; i<=l; i++)
```

You can Write like This

```
 for(int i = 0; i<=l-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j<=l-1; j++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j))
            {
                s = s.deleteCharAt(j);

            l--;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
```

Comment: What about the *inner loop*? `for(int j = i+1; j<=l; j++)` ? . And what about index `0`?

Comment: Or just simple `for(int i = 0; i<l; i++)` :P

Answer (score 0):

Correct your loop conditions :

```
 for(int i = 1; i < l; i++)
            {
                for(int j = i+1; j < l; j++)
                {
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `word.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1")` ?